# Convert string to generic type (basic or array) in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

I want to convert a string to a given generic type `T`. It may be either basic type or string (e.g. `int` or `string`), or an array of a basic types or strings (e.g. `int[]` or `string[]`). I have the following function:

```
T Str2Val<T>(string str)
{
  return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
}
```

It works well for basic types. But it fails for `T` being an array `E[]` and `str` being a comma-separated list of values.

I can easily check whether `T` is an array with `typeof(T).IsArray`. Then I have two solutions: parse an array in the same function with a scalar, like the following:

```
  if (!typeof(T).IsArray)
  {
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
  }
  else
  {
    // Handle an array
  }
```

or implement two overloaded functions: one for generic `T` and second for generic `E[]`. However, both of solutions fail. I cannot use any array-specific code in the else-clause since it must be compatible with a scalar. And C# cannot pick proper overload with `E[]` when `T` is actually an array.

What should I do?

Comment: How are you going to convert string to array and to array of what? `char[]`? use `ToCharArray`. `int[]`? How are you going to split it: comma, dash, dot?

Comment: I don't want to convert string to array. String should be converted to string (i.e. no changes). Array of strings is of now interest for my task, so whatever splitting is acceptable. Arrays of numbers should be splat with commas.

Comment: So are you trying to convert `int[]` to `string`?

Comment: No, for `T == int[]` I'm trying to convert `string` to `int[]`, like `"1,2,3"` to `{1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: You wrote in previous post `I don't want to convert string to array.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for this, I meant I don't want to convert string to array when `T==string` or `T==string[]`.

Comment: Well, ok, I think you should use Chris Sinclair solution. It is a little bit over-engineered, but I think you need a little bit of flexibility when using convertions, generics and reflection in one place

Comment: You should check if `T` implements `IConvertible`. Otherwise, there's no hope it will succeed with `Convert.ChangeType`. You could do like this: `if (typeof(IConvertible).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))) { return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T)); } /* otherwise, check if T is a collection, and so on. */`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create some listing of custom parsers that you register then later leverage since you seem to be wanting to use custom rules anyway:

```
public static class StringParsers
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, object> Parsers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static void RegisterParser<T>(Func<string, T> parseFunction)
    {
        Parsers[typeof(T)] = parseFunction;
    }

    public static T Parse<T>(string input)
    {
        object untypedParser;
        if (!Parsers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out untypedParser))
            throw new Exception("Could not find a parser for type " + typeof(T).FullName);

        Func<string, T> parser = (Func<string, T>)untypedParser;

        return parser(input);
    }
}
```

During your application initialization, you would register the types you intend to use later in your application (I'm guessing this is known since you're using generics):

```
StringParsers.RegisterParser<string[]>(input => input.Split(','));
StringParsers.RegisterParser<int[]>(input => input.Split(',').Select(i => Int32.Parse(i)).ToArray());
StringParsers.RegisterParser<int>(input => Int32.Parse(input));
```

Finally, you can call it simply:

```
string testArrayInput = "1,2,8";

int[] integers = StringParsers.Parse<int[]>(testArrayInput); // {1, 2, 8}

string[] strings = StringParsers.Parse<string[]>(testArrayInput); // {"1", "2", "8"}

int singleInt = StringParsers.Parse<int>("9999"); //9999
```

Now, this is a pretty simple implementation. You may wish to extend it so instead of using type `Func<string, T>` it might use an `IStringParser` interface and you can provide deeper implementations of the parsing if necessary. Furthermore, you may wish to make it thread safe (unless you're sure that won't be an issue, or if you are sure your registration on startup is *before* any usages)

EDIT: If you really, really, *really* want it all in one function *just* accounting for your comma delimited array, then you can use this:

```
public static T Str2Val<T>(string str)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsArray)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));

    Type elementType = typeof(T).GetElementType();

    string[] entries = str.Split(',');
    int numberOfEntries = entries.Length;

    System.Array array = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, numberOfEntries);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
        array.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(entries[i], elementType), i);

    return (T)(object)array;
}
```

But this feels so *wrong*. There must be a better way and to avoid the double generic input in Alexander's answer, but there you go.

Comment: Are you sure the conversion `(Func<string, T>)untypedParser;` is possible for `T` being an array?

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, The code above is tested and working. `T` when called is already type (for example) `int[]`.

Comment: Ok, I think it is a working solution. Though it's really high price for just being able to handle arrays, compared with my initial one-line function. Anyway, thanks for it.

Comment: @Mikhail I added an edit with an all-in-one function, but I don't like it. :) (also tested and working)

Comment: My god, it works! I have no idea why `(T)(object)` works while just `(T)` doesn't, but it's what I need! And it's the only thing I thought is impossible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And in fact, this code is simplified and list splitting is done one routine higher, so there is no hard dependency on this format.

Comment: @Mikhail The `(T)(object)` cast is because `var array` is a `System.Array` (now edited above to get rid of `var`). Your type `T` isn't defined to be convertable to an array; it is _sometimes_ but not for all cases (how could we natively cast an `int` to `int[]`?) However, at runtime, we _know_ it's compatible (from `if (!typeof(T).IsArray`) but the compiler doesn't know that. However, C# allows us to cast to/from `object` at compile time, so we simply cast the `System.Array` to `Object` from which we can cast to our type `T`.

Comment: @Mikhail BTW, this won't work for multidimensional or jagged arrays, but I'm guessing that's not an issue for your usage anyway. (my original code that allows for custom converters would work though)

Comment: Yeah, multidimensional arrays is not my case. Internally, this function is used to parse query string in an ASP.NET web-site application. Thank you for explanation on how `(T)(object)` works!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with explicit element type passing:

```
static T Str2Val<T>(string str)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));
}

static E[] Str2Val<T, E>(string str)
    where T : ICollection<E>
{
    return str.Split(',').Select(x => (E)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(E))).ToArray();
}
```

using

```
Str2Val<int>("1")
Str2Val<int[], int>("1,3")
```

Comment: Nice, but it requires changes in the interface of `Str2Val` and code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help:

```
dynamic Str2Val<T>(string str)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsArray)
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(str, typeof(T));

    var elementType = typeof(T).GetElementType();
    return str.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ChangeType(x, elementType)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This will convert to `object[]`, not to `E[]`.