# How to convert a string to generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that has a signature that looks like this:

```
public IList<T> GetReferenceData<T>(TransactionManager transactionManager = null)
{
    IList<T> collection;
    var cacheData = DataCacheManager.Instance.GetCacheItem(typeof(T).Name);
    if (cacheData != null)
    {
        collection = (IList<T>)cacheData;
    }
    else
    {
        collection = this.GetReferenceDataNoCache<T>(transactionManager);
        DataCacheManager.Instance.AddCacheItem(typeof(T).Name, collection);
    }

    return collection;
}
```

I have another method that allows me to pass in a string, which converts that string to the appropriate type. I then want to call the above method.

```
public IList GetReferenceDataByType(string referenceType)
{
        // this works and returns the appropriate type correctly
        var type = this.GetEntity(referenceType); 

        // now I'm stuck
        return this.GetReferenceData<?>();
}
```

What replaces the question mark?

Comment: If you need this method there's probably something going wrong.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is not the issue. He already has the type. He want to obtains a fully resolved generic method based on variable type parameters

Comment: Could you post `GetReferenceData<T>` body?

Comment: @TimSchmelter request is coming from an SOA web service. It can't pass internal types. It is actually passing an enumeration. I just simplified the code to make it a string so that I didn't need to start posting enums as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want somethiong like this:

```
public IList GetReferenceDataByType(string referenceType)
{
        // this works and returns the appropriate type correctly
        var type = this.GetEntity(referenceType); 

        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("GetReferenceData");
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        return (IList) generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { null });
}
```

Note that `IList<T>` does not implement `IList` so that cast may fail.

Comment: Might be that the generic invoke cant detect the default parameter, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should invert your approach.
Instead of calling generic methods from non-generic alternatives, your `GetReferenceData` and `GetReferenceDataNoCache` should be rewritten as non-generic ones:

```
public IList GetReferenceData(Type type, TransactionManager transactionManager = null)
{
   // ...
}

private IList GetReferenceDataNoCache(Type type, TransactionManager transactionManager = null)
{
   // ...
}

public IList<T> GetReferenceData<T>(TransactionManager transactionManager = null)
{
    return (IList<T>)GetReferenceData(typeof(T), transactionManager);
}
```

Look at your code: the only benefit from `T` in `GetReferenceData<T>` is `typeof(T)`.
The rest of method is non-generic in fact.

Comment: While you have a good point, I have over 50 underlying reference tables to deal with. The generics save a fair amount of code.

Comment: How the quantity of tables is related to method structure?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your answer. I thought you were implying that I would need 50+ separate GetReferenceData(TypeX typeX... declarations.

Comment: @Junto: of course, no. I mean, that you're trying to call generic method from non-generic one. This makes sense, if the generic method is really does some generic stuff. But your `GetReferenceData`, in fact, use its type parameter only to retrieve the `Type` instance. The rest of method doesn't depend on type parameter and can be rewritten to be non-generic.

Answer (score 0):

Visit these websites

http://predicatet.blogspot.com/2009/04/c-string-to-generic-type-conversion.html!

[Universal generic type conversion from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653669/universal-generic-type-conversion-from-string)

[Convert string to generic type (basic or array) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257207/convert-string-to-generic-type-basic-or-array-in-c-sharp)

i hope it will help you